# How to reference only the used classes in Doxygen documentation

Tags: c#, doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have a solution that has 10 projects.

One of them is the primary project that contains ONLY one class with 2-3 functions.

These functions are using 4 classes that exist in 2 other projects in the solution.

I want to be able to make documentation only for one project but i want to include ONLY the definition of the USED classes. I cant figure it out how to do it.

If i put in INPUT only my desired primary project i dont get links to my used classes from other projects.

I don't have each class in its own file ..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the used classes were public, and the unused classes were not, you could turn off Extract_private, extract_package, etc to exclude them.